# Kotlin Efficiency for Iterator of One

Tags: kotlin, iterator, jvm

Given something that implements `Iterable<*>`.

Most implementations return an iterator that iterates `>1` values.

I'm creating a specific implementation that returns an iterator that iterates `1` value.

What is the best implementation?

Given the implementation implements `Iterable<Any>`, and has a property named `value` of type `Any`:

```kotlin
override fun iterator(): Iterator<Any> = iterator {
    return@iterator this.yield(this@ExampleIterable.value)
}
```

Is this the most efficient (*albeit, not most concise*) implementation of a single-element iterator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is far from the most efficient implementation on the JVM, if you are not considering conciseness. The following, for example, would be more efficient:

```
override fun iterator() = object: Iterator<Expression> {
    var nextCalled = false

    override fun hasNext() = !nextCalled

    override fun next(): Expression {
        if (nextCalled) {
            throw NoSuchElementException()
        }
        nextCalled = true
        return value
    }
}
```

or as an inline function:

```
inline fun <T> iteratorOfOne(crossinline elem: () -> T) = object: Iterator<T> {
    var nextCalled = false

    override fun hasNext() = !nextCalled

    override fun next(): T {
        if (nextCalled) {
            throw NoSuchElementException()
        }
        nextCalled = true
        return elem()
    }
}
```

For one, this doesn't use coroutines like the `iterator` function does, so it avoids a lot of the overhead that coroutines create. For something as simple as an iterator returning a single element, the overhead of coroutines could be quite a lot.

Looking at the bytecode, you can see that it first instantiates the inner class that represents the lambda `return@iterator this.yield(this@ExampleIterable.value)`, and then calls `SequencesKt.iterator`.

The lambda inner class actually implements state machine-like thing, kind of like what I did with `nextCalled`, but with an `Int` instead, and some added coroutine overhead.

For example, `iterator { yield(Any()) }` produces the following `invokeSuspend` implementation in the inner class (decompiled to Java):

```
int label;

@Nullable
public final Object invokeSuspend(@NotNull final Object $result) {
    final Object coroutine_SUSPENDED = IntrinsicsKt.getCOROUTINE_SUSPENDED();
    switch (this.label) {
        case 0: {
            ResultKt.throwOnFailure($result);
            final SequenceScope sequenceScope;
            final SequenceScope $this$iterator = sequenceScope = (SequenceScope)this.L$0;
            final Object o = new Object();
            final Continuation continuation = (Continuation)this;
            this.label = 1;
            if (sequenceScope.yield(o, continuation) == coroutine_SUSPENDED) {
                return coroutine_SUSPENDED;
            }
            break;
        }
        case 1: {
            ResultKt.throwOnFailure($result);
            break;
        }
        default: {
            throw new IllegalStateException("call to 'resume' before 'invoke' with coroutine");
        }
    }
    return Unit.INSTANCE;
}
```

Then `iterator` makes an `Iterator` implementation out of that coroutine. The [source code](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/f3385fbdcb8b9dc29661a8a4973c855cdcf73767/libraries/stdlib/src/kotlin/collections/SequenceBuilder.kt#L34) looks like this:

```
public fun <T> iterator(@BuilderInference block: suspend SequenceScope<T>.() -> Unit): Iterator<T> {
    val iterator = SequenceBuilderIterator<T>()
    iterator.nextStep = block.createCoroutineUnintercepted(receiver = iterator, completion = iterator)
    return iterator
}
```

Again, more stuff that doesn't actually need to happen, if you've just created and returned an instance of `Iterator<T>` yourself.

The point is, there is a lot of overhead with creating a whole coroutine just to make a single-element iterator. In the grand scheme of things, this might not matter - you probably have other code that does way more work than this - but if we are just comparing these things in a vacuum, then creating an anonymous class is faster.

Comment: Thank you @Sweeper. I should have known better previously being familiar with how C#/.NET's generators behave under the hood. Definitely an anonymous `Iterator<>` is favorable here. And also true, this is probably micro-optimization, but I don't know how this'd be abused in client code so better to keep it performant.